# Who and how defines the selling price for the Managed Package listed on the AppExchange

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

The context of the question.

---

Let's say, that company **Foo** has a standalone web application, which serves as a platform for managing leads, communicating with leads via different channels: WhatsApp, Facebook, SMS.

**Foo**  noticed, that a lot of their customers ask if, **Foo** has any integration with salesforce. Customers would like to have the possibility to send data from salesforce to platform and from platform to salesforce.

**Foo** managers, noticed, that it is a good possibility to make customers more satisfied and they built a **Foo Integration Managed Package**. This package allows configuring mapping between salesforce and the platform and having bi-directional data sync.

The Managed Package is in the middle of security review and seems all is good from a tech perspective.

From the business perspective **Foo Integration Managed Package** security review submitter needs to define the pricing model for the managed package. The submitter wants to choose AppExchange checkout as the instrument for selling the managed package.

According to the [How Is Revenue Shared in AppExchange Checkout?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_checkout_rev_share.htm) it clearly says, that there is a 15% revenue share using the checkout. Which is perfect.

---

and finally **questions**:

Who is setting the price for this managed package?

Is it defined by the package submitter, and submitter can set which price they want (using different payment plans, like one-time, subscription, per-user, per-org)?

Does salesforce recommend you a price?

Can salesforce be against selected by submitter price?

Can **Foo Integration Managed Package**  be listed on AppExchange with pricing model:

- one-time per company 1$;
- subscription per month per user 100000$.

For sure, this is better to discuss directly with salesforce support, using a support case, but still having that info would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Who is setting the price for this managed package?**

> This is the package vendor. Company **foo** in your example is free to set the price. Salesforce has no say in this.

**Does salesforce recommend you a price?**

> No, Salesforce lets the vendor decide the appropriate price tag.

**Can salesforce be against selected by submitter price?**

> No, Salesforce won't be against it. As a vendor you will choose the price, most of the apps do well if the price is as per the Market

**Can Foo Integration Managed Package be listed on AppExchange with pricing model?**

Yes, it's up to the package vendor to choose per user Model or a one-time flat fee per org per month.